# Validação de campo único em formulário no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gerencia inscrições em cursos, e no meu formulário de cadastro tenho o campo CPF, e gostaria de saber como eu faço para deixar esse campo único, ou seja, barrar o usuário de fazer outro cadastro com o mesmo CPF. Se o CPF já existir na tabela, o sistema deve barrar esse CPF existente e o usuário terá que informar outro CPF caso ele queira fazer um novo cadastro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemente um *Attribute* de CPF:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
    sealed public class CPFAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private MeuProjetoContext context = new MeuProjetoContext();

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;

            int soma = 0, resto = 0;
            string digito;
            int[] multiplicador1 = new int[9] { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
            int[] multiplicador2 = new int[10] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };

            string CPF = value.ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");

            if (CPF.Length != 11)
                return new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido.");

            if (Convert.ToUInt64(CPF) % 11111111111 == 0)
                return new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido.");

            if (validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType() == typeof(Pessoa))
            {
                var model = (Pessoa)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

                if (context.Pessoas.Any(p => (p.Cpf == CPF) && (p.PessoaID != model.PessoaID)))
                {
                    var message = FormatErrorMessage("CPF já está cadastrado.");
                    return new ValidationResult(message);
                }
            }

            string tempCpf = CPF.Substring(0, 9);

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador1[i];

            resto = soma % 11;
            if (resto < 2)
                resto = 0;
            else
                resto = 11 - resto;

            digito = resto.ToString();
            tempCpf = tempCpf + digito;
            soma = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];

            resto = soma % 11;

            if (resto < 2)
                resto = 0;
            else
                resto = 11 - resto;

            digito = digito + resto.ToString();

            if (CPF.EndsWith(digito))
                return null;
            else
                return new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido.");
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Use no seu *Model*:

```
[CPF] 
public String Cpf { get; set; }
```

A validação é feita pelo ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize na Controller um metodo que busca o cpf e também um metodo que verifica se o CPF é valido no mesmo método

```
 private void ValidaCpf(Aluno aluno)
    {

        if (aluno.cpf != null)
        {
            Aluno duplicatealuno = db.Alunos
            .Where(d => d.cpf == aluno.cpf)
            .FirstOrDefault();
            //verifica se o Cpf ´´e igual ao existente e verifica se o id é diferente do aluno cadastrado com o CPF
            if (duplicatealuno != null && duplicatealuno.cpf == aluno.cpf && duplicatealuno.id != aluno.id)
            {
                string errorMessage = String.Format(
                "CPF já cadastrado no sistema");
                //defina qual campo irá receber a mensagem e a mensagem
                ModelState.AddModelError("cpf", errorMessage);
            }

            if (!CpfValido(aluno.cpf))
            {
                string errorMessage = String.Format(
              "CPF inválido");
                ModelState.AddModelError("aluno.cpf", errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }

     #region Helpers
    public bool CpfValido(string cpf)
    {
        int[] multiplicador1 = new int[9] { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        int[] multiplicador2 = new int[10] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        string tempCpf;
        string digito;
        int soma;
        int resto;
        cpf = cpf.Trim();
        cpf = cpf.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
        if (cpf.Length != 11)
            return false;
        tempCpf = cpf.Substring(0, 9);
        soma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador1[i];
        resto = soma % 11;
        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;
        digito = resto.ToString();
        tempCpf = tempCpf + digito;
        soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];
        resto = soma % 11;
        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;
        digito = digito + resto.ToString();
        return cpf.EndsWith(digito);
    }

    #endregion
```

E antes de salvar utilize o método

```
ValidaCpf(aluno);
 //Caso o cpf exista ele ira mostrar a mensagem 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {}
```

Você pode adicionar na model a definição de campo unico, não tenho certeza se funciona em todos caso ou se esse é seu caso.

```
[Display(Name = "CPF")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, preencher o campo CPF.")]
    [Index("INDEX_CPF2", IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(14)]
    public string cpf { get; set; }
```

Comment: O problema desta forma é que ela é executada antes do ciclo normal de validação do MVC, podendo até ser considerada um anti-padrão.